# Problem with useRef React Hook and event listener and change img src

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a React Hook that will change image on mouseover event.  I've got the code below that does not work.  I was hoping I could add an event listener, then when the onmouseever event fires, change the image src attribute.  Here is the code that does not work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const ImageToggler = ({ primaryImg, mouseOverImg }) => {
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  function handleMouseOverHandler() {
    console.log("handleMouseOver");
    imageRef.current.src = mouseOverImg;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // THIS DOES NOT SEEM TO DO ANYTHING
    imageRef.current.addEventListener(
      "onmouseover",
      handleMouseOverHandler,
      true
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <img
      ref={imageRef}
      src={primaryImg}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        console.log("mouse over....");
      }}
      alt="image here"
    />
  );
};

export default ImageToggler;
```

Comment: It's `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`. You've already got onMouseOver. Why do you set the listener manually?

Comment: All I care about is swapping the img src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo, event's name is `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`.

There is no need for `useEffect` because there's no need to set event listener handler manually, this is already handled by React.

It should be:

```
   <img
      ref={imageRef}
      src={primaryImg}
      onMouseOver={handleMouseOverHandler}
    />
```

Comment: can we set `src` directly without `useRef`?

Comment: @skyboyer I guess we can, `const [src, setSrc] = useState(primaryImg)`, then use `src` as `src` prop and `setSrc` to set it in `handleMouseOverHandler`. This will behave differently when new `primaryImg` value is received, depends on how the OP expects it to behave.

Comment: I did not select this is the correct answer because I was going for adding and removing listeners. I realize I did not explain that clearly enough so chose it as correct answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass null to the function. It will delete the prototype of the current object. Instead do this

`const imageRef = useRef();`