# How To Simplify Event Functions in React DOM Listeners

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I've got the following code that declares a listener for mouse in and out of an image.  I'm doing it with a named function rather than a simple lamda so that I can carry a reference and then remove the listener when the component is removed.

**Is there a short hand way to get a reference to the handlers in a simpler way then I'm doing here**? I'm hoping I don't have to have explicitly function definitions like this. I prefer to keep the function definition inside the event add if possible.

This feels like a lot of ceremony I'm hoping I can cut down on.

```
const ImageToggler = ({ primaryImg, mouseOverImg }) => {
  const imageRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMouseOverHandler = () => {
    imageRef.current.src = mouseOverImg;
  };

  const handleMouseOutHandler = () => {
    imageRef.current.src = primaryImg;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    imageRef.current.addEventListener(
      "mouseover",
      handleMouseOverHandler,
      true
    );
    imageRef.current.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOutHandler, true);
    return () => {
      imageRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "mouseover",
        handleMouseOverHandler,
        false
      );
      imageRef.current.removeEventListener(
        "mouseout",
        handleMouseOutHandler,
        false
      );
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: imageRef is set on the first render so that by the time the listener is added, there is a dom reference we an add the listener to.  FYI, this code works, I'm just trying to make it more concise if possible.  (see useRef docs)

Comment: I see. You didn't provide a feedback on previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168846/problem-with-useref-react-hook-and-event-listener-and-change-img-src . It exactly addresses the thing you're asking about, how to simplify this.

Comment: @estus . I understand why you think it has been addressed but it does not. I asked a very specific question and that was about simplifying what I have here, not replacing it with something else. This is for courseware and I want to demonstrate with removeListener even though in this case it's not the most optimal way to do it. If there is a better way to handle addlistener and removelistener I'd like to know that. (not by replacing them)

Comment: It's already concise enough. You can extract this to custom hook if you have this code in multiple places. Using React event handling is the only way it can be simplified here. Is there a reason why you didn't use onMouseOver, etc. props?

Comment: Like I said the only reason I did not use onMouseOver (which I agree is a better way to do it) is I want to demonstrate how to do cleanup with useEffects and a typical place people forget to clean up is when they add listener without removing them. I couldn't come up with a better example that could not easily be done with props or was something that was more complex (like the spring library) then I want to explain in the course.

Comment: If your goal is to demonstrate useEffects, I'd recommend finding a different example--setting up event listeners using refs (rather than passing event handlers when rendering) is a common anti-pattern among people new to React, and seeing it in an example will just encourage that.

Comment: @PeterKellner Setting up listeners manually would only be justified if an element were external. Since an image is a direct child, `addEventListener` isn't needed. A common case for what you're doing is is `window` scroll listener. If you want a concise real-world example, that's it. And yes, it should be done exactly like you're doing with useEffect. This is a counterpart to componentDidMount/componentWIllUnmount pair.